# How to update a CGFrame?

Tags: objective-c

The following code has a (at least one) deep flaw: Once `CGFrame` is set it's location is fixed.

```
-(UIImageView*) ownImageView {

    if (ownImageView == nil) {
        ownImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                  CGRectMake(self.xPosition, self.yPosition, 
                  [constants cardWidth], [constants cardHeight])];

        [ownImageView setImage:self.faceImage];
    }

    return ownImageView;
}
```

I would like to reuse the `UIImageView` (once created, I don't want to realloc it). Instead, i'd like to change x,y coordinates of the frame it contains.

The following code works fine, however, it seems carelessly wasteful

```
-(UIImageView*) ownImageView {

    [ownImageView removeFromSuperview];
    ownImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
               CGRectMake(self.xPosition, self.yPosition, 
               [constants cardWidth], [constants cardHeight])];

    [ownImageView setImage:self.faceImage];

    return ownImageView;
}
```

**Question**: How would you handle this, while keeping as much of lazy instantiation as possible?

The view represents a 2d rectangle moving along the screen. I'd like to represent the "move" by simply changing X/Y position of the existing view instead of replacing it with a new copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ownImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move it the simplest thing to do is to let Core Animation do the work for you.
For more details and options check [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.THE_VIEW.center = CGPointMake(200, 200);
                //  OR you can change it's frame if you prefer
                 } 
                 completion:NULL];
```